# Core Data Relationship NSOrderedSet returning different order on each device

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsset, nsorderedset

I have several one-to-many relationships in my data model. In each case it is important that the order of the data retrieved from the model matches the order in which it was inserted. I have ticked the 'Ordered' box in the inspector for each relationship. I add the data as follows:

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *set = [destinationEntity mutableOrderedSetValueForKey:relationshipKey];
[set addObject:sourceEntity];
[CoreDataFunctions saveEntity:destinationEntity];
```

I subsequently retrieve the set as follows:

```
NSOrderedSet *set = [sourceEntity valueForKey:relationshipKey];
```

On the device on which the data were added this works fine - I can add multiple entities and they always display in the correct order. The problem is that on devices which have received the data through iCloud synchronisation, the set is returned in a different order. Always the same order mind you, but not the same order as entered on the original device.

To get around this I have added an 'order' attribute which is populated by an incrementing integer when inserting the objects into the set. I can then sort the set by that key after retrieving it from the data model. However, I can't help but feel that something is wrong if the NSOrderedSet is not coming back in a predictable order.

I wonder whether this is related to some errors I see in the log when a device is receiving transactions from iCloud. I see the following many times, presumably once for each transaction:

> *** ERROR: this process has called an NSArray-taking method, such as initWithArray:, and passed in an NSSet object.  This is being worked-around for now, but will soon cause you grief.

I assume this is because the objects in the data model are of type NSSet, and Core Data is passing them to something expecting an NSArray. I have no idea what I can do about this, however, or if it is related to this problem. I assume that it is, as I suspect that Core Data is converting the NSOrderedSet to an NSArray and losing the ordering in the process. I cannot confirm this though.

Any advice gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reliable way to do this is to create an `Abstract Entity` like `BaseEntity` from which every other class in your data model inherits. `BaseEntity` would have a `dateCreated` property that you set in `awakeFromInsert` in your `NSManagedObject` subclass.

Then when you perform a fetch request you can specify the `NSSortDescriptor` to sort using the `dateCreated` this is pretty quick especially if you're using `SQLite`.

If you do this then you can uncheck the `ordered` button in CoreData.

EDIT: Here is an example of ordering relationships in a managed object subclass:

Given an entity `Entity` with a CoreData generated relationship property:

```
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<Entity *> *toManyRelationship;
```

You can then create your own property:

```
@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray<Entity *> *orderedToManyRelationship;
```

This is implemented like so:

```
@dynamic toManyRelationship;

- (NSArray<Entity *> *)orderedToManyRelationship
{
    NSSortDescriptor *dateSorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateCreated" ascending:YES];

    return [[self.toManyRelationship allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[dateSorter]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Just a few questions. 1st, would this approach mean using NSManagedObject subclasses for my entities? I'm currently using helper methods and KVC so I have more control over the setting of values and saving. E.g., I have a helper method to set the key/value on an entity and then save the entity. 2nd, would this approach make a difference if I get relationship sets without using a fetch request? E.g., by accessing the attribute containing the set directly. 3rd, would date created work if entities are created rapidly (i.e. within less than a second of each other)?

Comment: OK so 1) Not necessarily all your entities but the the simplest way would be to subclass your `BaseEntity`. Note: Subclassing may be beneficial because you get type checking and IDE autocompletion, saves on annoying errors. 2) If you access the attribute directly then you'll have to apply a `sort descriptor` to the returned objects. (If you subclass you can do this in the class itself.) 3) Yes as long as they're inserted into the `NSManagedObjectContext` IN THE ORDER THEY"RE CREATED.

Comment: Thank you @RASS, this was very helpful. I also realised that my saving strategy was highly inefficient (basically saving the context every time an attribute value was changed...) I have now implemented a timed saving method which only saves when changes are detected and no more than once per 2 seconds. I will implement managed object subclasses in the manner you have described as it seems like a highly logical solution to the problem. Many thanks again!

Comment: Ahh brilliant idea! So I can embed a sorting method into the entity subclasses to get the entities out in the order I want. Genius! ;)

Comment: I just wanted to follow up again on this answer. Creating an abstract `BaseEntity` class on which to base my other entities and giving it a `dateadded` attribute which is populated with `[NSDate date]` on `awakeFromInsert` was exactly the right approach. I was then able to remove the `ordered` status of each of my relationships and sort on `myentity.date` in my fetch requests. Thanks again!

Comment: Not a problem. CoreData gets much nicer the longer you use it.

Comment: I can't believe I resisted CoreData and used sqlite3 for so long. NSFetchedResultsController is absolutely incredible. Seeing my UITableViews update automatically when data are changed on another device is mindblowing, and it's all so easy once you get your head around it! I'm not intending to update all my previous apps to use iCloud and CoreData.....